# Affine invariance of random projection outlyingness

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, random-matrices, projection-matrices, multivariate-statistical-analysis

I wish to prove the affine *invariance* property of the following outlyingness measure: $O(x,X) = \underset{\left\lVert u \right\rVert=1}{sup} \dfrac{\lvert u^T x - Med(u^T X) \rvert}{MAD(u^T X)}$

The equality I want to prove is therefore O(Ax+b, AX+b) = O(x, X) for any non-singular matrix $A$ and any $b \in R^d$, with $X$ the data matrix containing the $n$ samples with $d$ dimensions. What I got to, with $w=A^Tu$:

\begin{align}
    O(Ax+b) &= \underset{\left\lVert u \right\rVert=1}{sup} \dfrac{\lvert u^T (Ax+b) - Med(u^T (AX+b)) \rvert}{MAD(u^T (AX+b))} \\
            &= \underset{\left\lVert u \right\rVert=1}{sup} \dfrac{\lvert u^T Ax - Med(u^T AX) \rvert}{MAD(u^T AX)} \\
            &= \underset{\left\lVert u \right\rVert=1}{sup} \dfrac{\lvert w^T x - Med(w^T X) \rvert}{MAD(w^T X)} \\
            &= (...) \\
            &=? ~ O(x)
\end{align}

This affine invariance is put forward in this [document](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-28/issue-2/General-notions-of-statistical-depth-function/10.1214/aos/1016218226.pdf) (p.11 of the [pdf](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-28/issue-2/General-notions-of-statistical-depth-function/10.1214/aos/1016218226.pdf)):

> Theorem 2.9. The projection depth function PD(x;F) is a statistical
> depth function in the sense of Definition 2.1.

where `Definition 2.1` first property is the desired affine invariance. The proof of this invariance is however described as "straightforward" (p. 19 of the [pdf](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-28/issue-2/General-notions-of-statistical-depth-function/10.1214/aos/1016218226.pdf)):

> (a) Affine invariance. Straightforward.

Note that this document talks about the affine invariance of the projection (statistical) depth $PD(x, X) = \frac{1}{1+O(x,X)}$, but $PD(Ax+b)=PD(x)$ (omitting $(.,X)$ for conciseness) if and only if $O(Ax+b)=O(x)$. The latter equality, i.e. the affine invariance I'm looking for, is also put forward in this [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journalArticle/Download?urlId=10.1214%2Faos%2F1176348890): on p.6 of the pdf "outlyingness is affine invariant", where p.3 puts forward `Lemma 2.1` which states the statistical depth built with $O(x, X)$ is affine invariant as well. In the proofs at the end of the document, I don't see what I'm looking for (see p.19 of the [pdf](https://projecteuclid.org/journalArticle/Download?urlId=10.1214%2Faos%2F1176348890)).

It would seem that this affine *invariance* is related (equivalent ?) to the affine *equivariance* of the location and scatter estimators used in $O(x, X)$, these estimators being the `Med` (median) and the `MAD` (median absolute deviation) respectively, as suggested in this other [math.SE post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/243336/241224) and in the introduction of this [paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s11222-012-9352-6.pdf) :

> Furthermore, with a proper choice of (μ, σ ), it can induce a lot of
> favorable estimators, such as Stahel-Donoho location and scatter
> estimators, which enjoy very high breakdown point robustness and
> affine equivari- ance (Zuo et al. 2004; Zuo 2006), and projection
> median, which has the highest breakdown point among all the exist- ing
> affine equivariant multivariate location estimators (Zuo 2003).

This affine *equivariance* is also mentioned in this other [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.09117.pdf) (see p.3 of pdf), for example (there is a lot of papers mentioning the random projection depth & associated outlyingness). The affine *invariance* of $O(x, X)$ is also mentioned [here](https://personal.utdallas.edu/%7Eserfling/papers/Equivariance_November2009.pdf), where the loss of the invariance for a finite set of random projections is also put forward (with a solution to mitigate it):

> For ∆ the set of all projections, this is the usual projection
> outlyingness (e.g., see Zuo, 2003) and is affine invariant. However,
> for ∆ finite, not even orthogonal invariance holds.

Intuition could be that, since we have a data standardization anyway, the affine transformation has no impact on the outlyingness score $O(x, X)$, but I would like to have the complete and rigorous equations development.